# JWT: passing a new token to client at one minute or less from expiring. Bad idea or good?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

In my backend i check how long it is left before the JWT expires (15 min). If it is one minute or less i create a new one and attach it to the response in a setToken header.
The front will then store and use the new one. Is this a good approach? Opinions on the matters?

Thanks

Comment: I think his question is legit and well done

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is good. You are implementing a token refresh algorithm.
Depends of use cases, but it could be better to give back a new fresh token more frequently, not only when the token is going to expire in the next minute.

For example, a common approach is to give back a fresh token with a probability distribution (for example, each requests has a probability of 30% to send back a fresh token) combined with a timing algorithm like yours. So, for each request:

```
if (30% of times true || token is expiring in next n seconds)
    give a new refresh token.
```

The probability distribution is used to limit che cpu usage required for signing.

Another approach is to implement an API (let's say `GET /token`) that will just verify the provided JWT, and if it's valid, generate a new fresh JWT as response. With this approach, the "when to refresh" logic is moved to the client. The client should decide when to call the `/token` API to refresh his token. And usually this is done when the web application / mobile application starts. Or every n minutes if you are using JWT for server to server comunication.

In my opinion, the second approach is preferible.

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view this not really a good idea. The problem is not a security one but rather a logical one.

You are mixing access to the resources with the issuance of the tokens. If the client needs a token, it should explicitly ask for a new one and contact the dedicated endpoint. If the token expired, your server may need additional information (refresh token, verification of the credential materials...).

With your flow, the client will receive a token it haven't asked for. Furthermore, in addition to your application logic your client has to check if a new token is present for each single request. It may miss new access tokens and loose the access rights if the old one expired.

At last but not least, this new token may be useless and never used by the client.